# For what $a$ are the events $\{\max(1-2x,y) < a\}$ and $\{\max(1-2y,x) < a\}$ independent if $x,y \sim Uni(0,1)$?

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> Random variables $x,y$ are independently uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. For what values $a$ does events $\{\max(1-2x,y) < a\}$ and $\{\max(1-2y,x) < a\}$ are independent?

My solution is as following. Let $A = \big\{ \max{(1-2x,y)} < a \big\}$ and $B = \big\{ \max{(1-2y,x)} < a \big\}$. It is easy to plot $A, B$ and $A \cap B$ for fixed $a$. For example, for $a = \frac{3}{4}$ we have:
[image]

And from this we can figure out $P(A), P(B)$ and $P(A\cap B)$, calculating them as area of the corresponding rectangles:

$$P(A) = P(B) = a \times (1 - \frac{1-a}{2})$$
$$P(A \cap B) = (a - \frac{1-a}{2})^2$$

And now to get our values of $a$ we just have to solve the equation for identity $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$:

$$(a - \frac{1-a}{2})^2 = [a \times (1 - \frac{1-a}{2})]^2$$

Solving it, we receive four roots $1; 1; -2 - \sqrt{5}$ and $\sqrt{5} - 2$. We know, that for $a \geq 1$ and $a \leq 0$ we already have independence, because probabilities of our events equal 1 and 0. So the only interesting root for us is $\sqrt{5} - 2$.

So, the final answer is: $A$ and $B$ are independent for $a \geq 1$, $a \leq 0$ and $a = \sqrt{5} - 2$.

Is such a solution correct? On exam I received 0 points for it and do not see why. I can't access my actual solution right now, only grades. Maybe on exam I made a mistake in calculations (in the solution above I derived calculations using wolfram).

Comment: If I recall properly, in the original question there was no independence assumption.  The solution is correct with the independence assumption (assuming the algebra bit is correct), but this leaves open the question of finding $a$ for \emph{general} (maybe not independent) $X,Y$ in $\operatorname{Unif}[0,1]$.  Maybe this explains no-credit.

Comment: I think you may have forgotten to take into account that $P(A \cap B) = 0$ when $a < (1-a)/2$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you had to use $$P(A \cap B) = 
\left(1-a - \frac{1-a}{2}\right)^2$$