# Find $a$ so that $\max{(1-2x, y)}$ < a and $\max{(1-2y, x)} < a$ are independent

Tags: probability, solution-verification, independence, uniform-distribution

Let $x \sim U[0, 1]$, $y \sim U[0, 1]$. Let $M_1$ = $\max(1-2x,y)$, $M_2 = \max(1-2y,x)$. 
Find values of $a$ so that events $M_1 \leq a$ and $M_2 \leq a$ are independent.

This question has already been [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2320882/for-what-a-are-the-events-max1-2x-y-a-and-max1-2y-x-a-in?rq=1), and no answer was provided. I decided to tackle it myself and bring the attention.

**My solution**

Recall that $M_1 \leq a$ and $M_2 \leq a$ are independent iff $$P(M_1\leq a)P(M_2 \leq a) = P(M_1 \leq a, M_2 \leq a)$$
Since $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative, $M_1$ and $M_2$ are also nonnegative, therefore 
$$P(M_1 \leq a)=P(M_2\leq a) = P(M_1 \leq a, M_2 \leq a) = 0 \space \text{if a} \leq0$$
On the other hand, $M_1$ and $M_2$ do not exceed $1$, so 
$$P(M_1 \leq a) = P(M_2 \leq a) = P(M_1\leq a, M_2 \leq a) = 1 \space \text{if a} \geq 1$$
What if $a \in [0, 1]$?

Consider $P(M_1 < a, M_2 < a)$, which equals to: 
$$P(1-2x<a, y<a, 1-2y<a, x<a) = P\bigg(\frac{1-a}{2} < x < a\bigg) \cdot P\bigg(\frac{1-a}{2} < y < a\bigg) = P^{2}\bigg(\frac{1-a}{2} < x < a\bigg) = \bigg(a - \frac{1-a}{2}\bigg)^2 = \bigg(\frac{3a-1}{2}\bigg)^2$$ $\tag{1}$

On the other hand, 
$$P(M_1 < a) \cdot P(M_2<a) = P(x>\frac{1-a}{2}, \space y < a) \cdot P(y > \frac{1-a}{2}, \space x < a) = P^{2}\bigg(x > \frac{1-a}{2}, \space y < a \bigg) = \bigg(\frac{a(a+1)}{2}\bigg)^2$$ $\tag{2}$

Putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together, we obtain an equation
$$\bigg(\frac{3a-1}{2}\bigg)^2 = \bigg(\frac{a(a+1)}{2}\bigg)^2$$
Note that those are the squares of probabilities, so we can drop the squares and only look for roots of $$\frac{3a-1}{2} = \frac{a(a+1)}{2}$$ such that the both sides are in $[0, 1]$ interval. 
Only $a = 1$ satisfies. Thus, the final answer is
$$a \leq 0, a \geq 1$$

Comment: That looks reasonable though I think $P(M_1 < a , M_2 < a)= \left(\min\left(1,\max\left(0,\frac{3a-1}{2}\right)\right)\right)^2$ - in particular when $0 \le a \le \frac13$ (though also $a \lt 0$ and $a \gt 1$ )